# Does the nine point circle generalise to some theorem about n-spheres and n-simplices?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am obsessed with [the nine point circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-point_circle). I was thinking, is there a generalisation to aribtrary tetrahedra and spheres? What about higher dimensions? For each face of the tetrahedron, there is a nine point circle. Do these circles all lie on a sphere?

Comment: +1 - I wonder if there are any interesting mechanical constructions that make use of its properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An *orthocentric* tetrahedron is one for which the altitudes from the vertices to the opposite faces are concurrent (this is not true for all tetrahedrons).  For an orthocentric tetrahedron, there exists a sphere (the 24-point sphere) that intersects each face of the tetrahedron in its 9-point circle.

See also the summary of a talk by Steve West ("Discovering Theorems Using Cabri 3-D") in [the November 2008 issue of *Points & Angles* (PDF)](http://mmcchicago.org/dinners08-09/November08.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at:

http://www.springerlink.com/content/mj55u41710w625j8/

and

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron

There is also this paper that deals with sphere analogues:

http://www.jstor.org/pss/3617834

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken, and I'm also unable to find any copy saved on the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/)...