# Nine-point circle equivalent for tetrahedrons?

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

Nine-point circle for a triangle is defined as the circle that passes through:

- the midpoint of each side
- the foot of each altitude
- the midpoint of the line segment from each vertex to the orthocenter

[image]

It is amazing that all these points belong to a single circle.

> Is there an equivalent of nine-point circle for tetrahedron? Perhaps,
>   let's say, some "Fourty-four-point sphere"?

I searched available literature, but couldn't find anything.

*(NOTE: For Euler line of a triangle, there is an equivalent for tetrahedron)*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the nine point circle generalise to some theorem about n-spheres and n-simplices?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4854/does-the-nine-point-circle-generalise-to-some-theorem-about-n-spheres-and-n-simp)

Comment: @ElThor Yeah, I noticed that question after I posted this one. This one is more specific though. I wish someone wrote a more detailed explanation than one found in the answers to another question.

Comment: Fair enough. After looking more closely at those answers I too think that they deserve more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted elsewhere, we may want to restrict attention to *orthocentric* tetrahedra, which is the family of tetrahedra whose altitudes share a common point that we can call "the orthocenter". Such tetrahedra can be characterized various ways apart from the orthocentricity property; most importantly: each pair of opposite edges determine an orthogonal vectors (hence the alternative name "orthogonal tetrahedra").

[This answer to the related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4877/409) mentions that orthogonal tetrahedra admit a sphere that intersects each face's $9$-point circle; this is the tetrahedron's **24-point sphere**. (That's the topic of the [*Mathematical Gazette* article](http://www.jstor.org/pss/3617834) mentioned in [the other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4855/409).) Interesting. I've found another analogue, albeit with fewer than twenty-four points.

---

Place the coordinates of tetrahedron $ABCD$ at
$$A=(0,0,-a) \qquad B=(0,0,b) \qquad C=(h,-c,0) \qquad D=(h,d,0)$$
Here, $h$ is the length of the "edge altitude" between $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CD}$. (An edge altitude has its endpoints within two opposite edges, and it determines the unique line perpendicular to both of those edges.) The given coordinates ensure that $\overrightarrow{AB}\perp\overrightarrow{CD}$; we guarantee the orthogonality of the other two pairs of opposing edge-vectors with the relation
$$h^2 = a b + c d$$
The coordinates of the orthocenter are 
$$Q = \left(\frac{ab}{h}, 0, 0\right)$$
(Fun fact: Orthogonal tetrahedra are also characterized as those whose three edge altitudes concur. Moreover, the edge altitudes and face altitudes all meet *at the same point*, $Q$.)

Without too much trouble, one can find the feet of the four face altitudes. These determine a sphere with center $S$ and radius $s$, where
$$S = \left(\frac{a b + h^2}{3 h}, \frac{-c + d}{6}, \frac{-a + b}{6}\right) \qquad
s^2 = \frac{h^2\left( (a+b)^2 + (c+d)^2 \right) - 4 a b c d}{36 h^2}$$

One can verify that this sphere contains

- The centroid of each face: $\frac13(A+B+C)$, etc.
- The one-third-point of the segment *from* the orthocenter *to* each vertex: $\frac13(A+2Q)$, etc.

These points are analogues, respectively, of the midpoint of each edge (eg, $\frac12(A+B)$), and the midpoint of the orthocenter-vertex midpoint (eg, $\frac12(A+Q)$), in a triangle's 9-point circle. (Intriguingly, we go from "halves" in *two* dimensions to "thirds" in *three* dimensions. Does this pattern continue?)

This sphere *does not* contain the midpoint of each edge, and therefore does not contain the $9$-point circle of each face; this sphere is distinct from the $24$-point sphere.

---

I'm currently unaware of any other "interesting" points that may lie on this sphere. (So, for now, it's merely a "$12$-point sphere".) I'll note that the edge intersections aren't particularly pretty; for instance, if $\frac{1}{1+m}(A+mB)$ is on the sphere, then
$$m = \frac{a + b \pm \sqrt{a^2 - 14 a b + b^2}}{4 b}$$

---

**Edit.** The appearance of a "1/3" at the (now-deleted) end of my original answer got me thinking a little bit more about the [powers of points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) with respect to various spheres, which I'll denote $\Sigma$ (the circumsphere), $\Sigma_{24}$ (the 24-point sphere), and $\Sigma_{12}$ (the 12-point sphere described above):

$$\begin{array}{rccclr}
\operatorname{pow}(Q,\Sigma_{12}) &=& -\dfrac{a b c d}{3h^2} &=& \phantom{-}\color{red}{\dfrac13}\;\operatorname{pow}(Q,\Sigma_{24}) = \left(\color{red}{\dfrac13}\right)^2 \; \operatorname{pow}(Q,\Sigma)  \\[6pt]
\operatorname{pow}(A,\Sigma_{12}) &=& \dfrac{2a(a+b)}{3} &=& \phantom{-}\color{red}{\dfrac13}\;\operatorname{pow}(A,\Sigma_{24}) \color{gray}{\qquad(\operatorname{pow}(A,\Sigma_{\phantom{24}}) = 0)} \\[6pt]
\operatorname{pow}(H,\Sigma_{12}) &=& \dfrac{ab}{3} &=& -\color{red}{\dfrac13}\; \operatorname{pow}(H,\Sigma_{\phantom{24}}) \color{gray}{\qquad(\operatorname{pow}(H,\Sigma_{24}) = 0)}
\end{array}$$
where $H$ is the endpoint in $\overline{AB}$ of the edge altitude $h$. (In our coordinatized tetrahedron, $H$ lies at the origin.) As it happens, all six such endpoints lie on the 24-point sphere, as each is the foot of an altitude in a face. (Importantly, altitudes from neighboring faces meet at these points. For instance, the altitude from $C$ in face $\triangle ABC$, and the altitude from $D$ in face $\triangle ABD$, meet at $H$.)

I'm not sure what (if anything) this is trying to tell me, but it's pretty neat.

Comment: For me, your sphere is in spirit better analogue to 9-point circle than the sphere mentioned elsewhere.